# Remove whole node from XML document based on name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML from which i have to take only those nodes with  having 4 char 
output will be xml doxument
input :

```
<File>
  <book>
    <Maths>50</Maths>
    <user>
      <Name>yash</Name>
    </user>
  </book>
  <book>
    <Maths>22</Maths>
    <user>
      <Name>Rahul</Name>
    </user>
  </book>
  <book>
    <Maths>33</Maths>
    <user>
      <Name>Dinesh sathe</Name>
    </user>
  </book>
</File>
```

output: xml Doc

```
<File>
    <book>
     <Maths>50</Maths>
     <user>
       <Name>yash</Name>
     </user>
    </book>
</File>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with below steps:

1.query the xml with name (4 char) :

```
  var query = from book in XDocument.Load("source.xml").Descendants("book")
                        where book.Element("user").Element("Name").Value.Count() == 4
                        select book;
```

2. save the result back to the xml file